# GridGain cannot bind to any port on Linux

Tags: java, gridgain

I get an exception like the one below:

```
Caused By:
>>> Type: java.io.IOException
>>> Message: Function not implemented
>>> Stack trace:
>>> at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollCreate(EPollArrayWrapper.java:1)
>>> at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.<init>(EPollArrayWrapper.java:59)
>>> at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.<init>(EPollSelectorImpl.java:52)
>>> at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorProvider.openSelector(EPollSelectorProvider.java:18)
>>> at org.gridgain.grid.util.nio.GridNioServer.createSelector(GridNioServer.java:110)
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

If you get such an exception then you need to update your operating system:

First, make sure that you use kernel 2.6+. Type following command that will print out Linux version and kernel version as well.

```
uname -a
```

If kernel version is less than 2.6 then we recommend to upgrade it.

If your kernel version is 2.6+ then check if you have latest `glibc` library installed or just update it to the latest.